# Linux local and external network issue

Tags: linux, networking

I have two linux servers one would be for database and other one to host http server. I have them connected to switch to use ips like 192.168.1.101 to connect to mysql. I am having issues with servers not being able to ping each other with local IP.. I have 2 other windows machines can ping from each other but the rocky linux ones are just not wanting to cooperate.. What is it that I am missing here?

```
[(01:33 AM)][(root@atf)] [(~)] $ ip route
default via 208.117.37.129 dev eno1np0 proto static metric 100
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2np1 proto static metric 101
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno2np1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.103 metric 101
208.117.37.129 dev eno1np0 proto static scope link metric 100 

[(01:33 AM)][(root@site)] [(~)] $ ifconfig
eno1np0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 208.*.*.*  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::3eec:efff:fec8:4b00  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:ec:ef:c8:4b:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15482764  bytes 20552671448 (19.1 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15477718  bytes 13958702853 (13.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno2np1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::3eec:efff:fec8:4b01  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:ec:ef:c8:4b:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 8634  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 1930039
        TX packets 59271  bytes 9698668 (9.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

(10:59 AM)][(root@site)] [(/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts)] $ ping -I eno2np1 192.168.1.101
PING 192.168.1.101 (192.168.1.101) from 192.168.1.103 eno2np1: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^Z
[2]+  Stopped
```

Comment: Given `eno2np1` has not received a single packet correctly - they are all showing errors, either you have a cabling or switch problem.